# Ajax and Django Like button

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

**my problem is i make like button with ajax but it only works for first post i need to refresh page for other posts**

i'm a little new to this job, can you check where the error is caused?
Like button works but I need to refresh the page
**could this be the problem id='...' or can html be affected by other scripts**
**my model**
mymodels.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
content =  models.ManyToManyField(PostFileContent, related_name='contents')
caption = models.TextField(max_length=1500, verbose_name='Caption')
posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, related_name='like', default=None, blank=True)
like_count = models.BigIntegerField(default='0')


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('postdetails', args=[str(self.id)])

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

myviews.py

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def like(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        result = ''
        id = request.POST.get('postid')
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            post.like_count -= 1
            result = post.like_count
            post.save()
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            post.like_count += 1
            result = post.like_count
            post.save()

        return JsonResponse({'result': result, })
```

mybutton.html

```
          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <button style="margin-top: 10px;" class="btn btn-light like_button_true like-button" value="{{ post_item.id }}">
            {% if post_item.like_count >= 2 %}
              <img style="width: 32px; height:32px;" src="{% static 'img/likeTrue.png' %}" />
            {% else %}
                <img style="width: 32px; height:32px;" src="{% static 'img/likeFalse.png' %}" />
            {% endif %}
            <br>
            <span id="like_count_{{ post_item.id }}">{{post_item.like_count}}</span>
          </button>
          {% endif %}
```

myscript

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.like-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "like" %}',
      data: {
        postid: $(this).val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("like_count_" + $(this).val()).innerHTML = json['result']
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

      }
    });
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i see more problem in project, but of course you have also a problem with the same id on html page. id for html element should be unique.

```
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <button style="margin-top: 10px;" class="btn btn-light like_button_true like-button" value="{{ post_item.id }}">
      {% if post.like_count >= 2 %}
        <img style="width: 32px; height:32px;" src="{% static 'img/likeTrue.png' %}" />
      {% else %}
          <img style="width: 32px; height:32px;" src="{% static 'img/likeFalse.png' %}" />
      {% endif %}
      <br>
      <span id="like_count_{{ post.id }}">{{post_item.like_count}}</span>
    </button>
  {% endif %}
```

and in script:

```
  <script>
    ...
    success: function (json) {
      document.getElementById("like_count_" + $(this).val()).innerHTML = json['result']
    },
    ...
  </script>
```

Comment: Your answer gave me hope but I still need to refresh the page to see the number of likes increased :( (I updated the question, can you take a look again?)

Comment: please add models post and likes, i try to reproduce it on my PC

Comment: I added my model.